# Overriding Core Admin Model not Adminhtml

Tags: admin, magento-1, model

I am trying to override `/app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/User.php` to my local but my override seem not to work. When I did some investigation I only find solution for adminhtml not admin.

here is my code:

`app/code/local/Invent/Admin/etc/config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Invent_Admin>
            <version>0.1</version>
        </Invent_Admin>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <admin>
                    <rewrite>
                        <resource_user>Invent_Admin_Model_Resource_User</resource_user>
                    </rewrite>
            </admin>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

then for `app/code/local/Invent/Admin/Model/Resource/User.php`

```
class Invent_Admin_Model_Resource_User extends Mage_Admin_Model_Resource_User{

  //my code goes here
}
```

then for `app/etc/modules/Invent_Admin.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Invent_Admin>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Invent_Admin>
        <Invent_Admin_Adminhtml>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Adminhtml />
            </depends>
        </Invent_Admin_Adminhtml>
    </modules>
</config>
```

I cant seem to find out where is the problem with the xml above. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To overwrite resource mode, you need to add the `resource` suffix to the model name tag.

In your case you need to replace:

```
        <admin>
                <rewrite>
                    <resource_user>Invent_Admin_Model_Resource_User</resource_user>
                </rewrite>
        </admin>
```

With:

```
        <admin_resource>
                <rewrite>
                    <user>Invent_Admin_Model_Resource_User</user>
                </rewrite>
        </admin_resource>
```